# How to restore locked files to unlocked status (Windows 11 Home)

Tags: file-locking, filelock

I have done a stupid thing and need help getting bailed out. I installed a file/folder lock app "EaseUS LockMyFile" (Windows 11 Home). I locked a couple of folders but wasn't happy with the app so I uninstalled it. But, I forgot to first unlock the folders I had previously locked before uninstalling.

Now the folders are no longer visible in my File Explorer tree (but I can find files within thse folders by searching for filenames!) So much for lock security. Anyway, I need help "unlocking" the marooned folders and restoring them to be visible and accessible in the File Explorer view. From there, I will look for another locker app. Can anyone help with the unlocking process please?

Comment: This question is better suited for [su]. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: have posted to Super User. Thanks for reply.